# Cannot resolve symbol HttpPost in android even though I have the libraries?

Tags: android

I am a bit new to Android and I need to upload an image to a server using HttpPost. However, when I'm going to do the necessary

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
```

I've found I cant even import the defaultHttpClient, making it impossible to create a new HttpPost and HttpClient. I have already added the necessary libraries to the libs folder in my project and also added the compile files lines to gradle.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: "I have already added the necessary libraries to the libs folder in my project and also added the compile files lines to gradle" -- you might wish to explain, in detail, what you thought "the necessary libraries" are and what "the compile files lines" were. To use Apache's independent HttpClient library for Android, you do not need local JARs, but instead [can pull in an artifact](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SDK 23, the only way to use Apache http client is import

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

into your gradle file.

The important fact is that the HttpClient has been deprecated since SDK 22, so a fix four you can be either downgrade your project to SDK 22 (not recommended), or use the HttpURLConnection as suggested at Android Developers webiste: 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html